# Error with camara capture Camera server died

Tags: android, android-camera

```
06-01 07:48:47.956: W/Camera(6961): Camera server died!
06-01 07:48:47.956: W/Camera(6961): ICamera died
06-01 07:48:47.956: E/Camera(6961): Error 100
```

I am calling a class to capture an image then processing that image (compressing it to 640*480) then sending it to server with some other data like lat,lng,md_code,....

**Every thing works fine on Galaxy Note II but when I am trying to test this with a small device 's front camera (Galaxy S Advance) showing this error.is ti device problem**

**My code follows**

**Calling from activity**

```
// checking a camera?
    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
    else 
    {
        cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();

        if (cameraId < 0) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry you don't have secondary camera",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Exit from application
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
        else 
        {
            camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
        }
    }

private int findFrontFacingCamera() 
{
    int cameraId = -1;
    // Search for the front facing camera
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) 
    {
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) 
        {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Front Facing Camera found");
            cameraId = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return cameraId;
}
//Calling camara to capture
camera.takePicture(null, null,new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext(), code, pwd, InOutAb, serverPort));
```

**PhotoHandler class**

```
public class PhotoHandler implements PictureCallback {

private final Context context;

String mdCode,pass,state,serverPortAddress;
public PhotoHandler(Context context, String code, String pwd,String InOutAb,String serverPort) {
    this.context = context;
    mdCode = code;
    pass = pwd;
    state = InOutAb;
    serverPortAddress = serverPort;
}

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imgData, Camera camera) {

    //Compressing the image 640*480
    //-----------------------------------------
    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgData, 0, imgData.length);
    Bitmap resizedBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 640, 480, false);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    resizedBmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
    //-----------------------------------------


    File pictureFileDir = getDir();

    if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Can't create directory to save image.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }


    String photoFile = "MyPicture.jpg";
    String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;
    File pictureFile = new File(filename);

    try 
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "New Image saved:" + filename,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
    catch (Exception error) 
    {
        Log.d("Exception", error+"");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Image could not be saved.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private File getDir() 
{
    File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    return new File(sdDir, "Attendance Image");
}
} 

**Not even single success toast is given only showing this error**
```